# Function argument with jQuery selector

Tags: jquery-selectors

Folks, this works correctly for me to hide any element where the class name starts with "o"

```
function hider() {$("*[class^=o]").hide();}
```

Now I'd like to be able to pass that "o" string in as the function's argument, and I have trouble with the syntax.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that something like this will work:

`function hider(startsWith) {
$("*[class^="+startsWith+"]").hide();
}`
try it in this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/JECUL/

Comment: Almost:  The 1st line below works, but only with the fixed argument.  The 2nd line fails quietly. `$("*[class^='z']").hide();` `$("*[class^="+startsWith+"]").hide();`  How can I pass the argument?

Comment: It works for me in both ways, tried it in the fiddle.
if that way fails try this: 

$("*[class^='"+startsWith+"']").hide();

But it works both ways so it should not matter.

Answer (score 2):

```
function hider(className) {$("*[class^="+className+"]").hide();}
```

Call like so

```
hider("o");
```